# Eloquent yelling about Undefined index : username

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I have this situation, I changed in `auth.php` the `'username'` from `username` to `email`so I have

```
'username' => 'email'
```

I don't have any `username` column anymore, but when trying to login, eloquent yell about undefined index : username :

```
.../laravel/auth/drivers/eloquent.php on line 39
```

- The method : http://paste.laravel.com/hWz
- The view : http://paste.laravel.com/hWA

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, Since we specify the `column` which will act as `username for eloquent`, The input array need to have a username value.

So in the login method I changed the userdata :

***before :***

```
$userdata = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'      => Input::get('password'),
        );
```

***after :***

```
$userdata = array(
            'username'      => Input::get('email'),
            'password'      => Input::get('password'),
        );
```

Comment: My bad, Sorry! the first array has 'email' key which is the eloquent 'username' so this key has to be 'username' and eloquent will match it with the email column in the database.